# Filter options in second select based on option selected in first select

Tags: jquery

I want to filter second select (#group_2) based on first select (#group_1), but it need to be filtered based on title attribute containgin title from #group_1 and sorted alphabetical skipping first option because it's (-- select --)

```
<select id="group_1">
   <option title="BMW">BMW</option>
   <option title="Toyota">Toyota</option>
   <option title="Ford">Ford</option>
<select>

<select id="group_2">
   <option title="BMW X3">BMW X3</option>
   <option title="BMW F30">BMW F30</option>
   <option title="Toyota Yaris">Toyota Yaris</option>
   <option title="Toyota Corolla">Toyota Corolla</option>
   <option title="Ford Forcus">Ford Focus</option>
   <option title="Ford Forcus">Ford K</option>
<select>
```

```
$('#group_2').first().hide();
$("#group_1").change(function() {
if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
  $(this).data('options', $('#group_2 option').clone());
  $('#group_2').first().show();
}
var id = $(this).attr('title');
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[title*=' + id + ']');
$('#group_2').html(options);
});
```

And the result is that I can select #group_1 (#group_2 is hidden but if I check it in source code options are avaiable) and after selection #group_1, #group_2 is showing but options are deleted (select list is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just needed to add `.find(":selected")` to:

```
var id = $(this).find(":selected").attr('title');
```

Your `id` was not producing the `tittle`, it was `undefined` because that was giving you a list of all options (if you did `for each`),  You need just `:selected` one.

```js
$('#group_2').first().hide();

$("#group_1").change(function() {
if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
  $(this).data('options', $('#group_2 option').clone());
  $('#group_2').first().show();
}
var id = $(this).find(":selected").attr('title');
console.log(id);

var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[title*=' + id + ']');
$('#group_2').html(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="group_1">
   <option title="BMW">BMW</option>
   <option title="Toyota">Toyota</option>
   <option title="Ford">Ford</option>
<select>

<select id="group_2">
   <option title="BMW X3">BMW X3</option>
   <option title="BMW F30">BMW F30</option>
   <option title="Toyota Yaris">Toyota Yaris</option>
   <option title="Toyota Corolla">Toyota Corolla</option>
   <option title="Ford Forcus">Ford Focus</option>
   <option title="Ford Forcus">Ford K</option>
<select>
```